# DecimalFormat not working on Windows 7, but working on Windows 8

Tags: java

I have an applet which is working fine on Windows 8, but on Windows 7 I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-0,9"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
at Tanc.Game$Corp.getDW(Game.java:1505)
at Tanc.Game.borders(Game.java:975)
at Tanc.Game.loose(Game.java:1068)
at Tanc.Game.gameLoop(Game.java:242)
at Tanc.Game$1.run(Game.java:144)
```

I have to mention that I tried on 2 different computers but the same problem. On Windows 8 I don't get this error...

And code

```
String zz = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(corp400.y);
    
    System.out.println(zz);
    
    if (Float.parseFloat(zz) == 0.2f)
        sw = true;
    if (Float.parseFloat(zz) == -0.24f)
        sw = false;code here
```

Comment: ahh I forgot one minute.

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem with locale: on the computer with Win8 there are locale, where `,` means decimal separator, but on the other tested computers `.` means decimal separator.

Comment: Yes I figured it out but how I solve this?
I tried `zz == "0.2" but it`s not working either.

Comment: 1. To solve it, you need to set proper locale to your applicaton (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api//java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale))<br> 2. What does mean "is not working"? What is the error message?

Comment: I get an error in java console read again the question and see the error and why it`s not working.And thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `DecimalFormat` with `(Math.round(corp400.y*100.0)/100.0)`
But if anyone can find out how to fix `DecimalFormat` to work with Windows 8 and windows 7 please Comment/Answer.

Comment: Why do you want to use formatting at all????? You format number to string and then back to number. Why don't you use original number????

Comment: because my original number is something like this 0.346453141234461 I need only o.34

Comment: So you should rather use a `BigDecimal` instead of float: `new BigDecimal(corp400.y).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

Comment: I never used BigDecimal and I don not know what it is. Thank you I will search for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably on windows 8 (where it works) you are using an English locale.

The problem, tough, is in the code:

```
String zz = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(corp400.y);
```

actually uses the default locale to format `corp400.y`, but the JavaDoc says that `Float.parseFloat`

> Returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Float.

This means that, since `Float.valueOf` parses a floating point literal, it expects decimals separated by `.`  not `,`

The correct way to reverse your locale-dependant formatting is:

```
float value = new DecimalFormat("#.##").parse(zz).floatValue();
```

Alternatively, you could use the locale-independent formatting on both ways as in:

```
String zz = String.valueOf(corp400.y);
float value = Float.parseFloat(zz)
```

Comment: `String zz = new DecimalFormat("#.##",otherSymbols).format(corp400.y); `
` otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
  otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
  otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(','); `